# Would a question about resources for learning CRM platforms be considered on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I asked on Superuser this question and was promptly closed. Would this question be better off here - I know Deltek Vision is mostly for AEC and it seems most PM on here is related to software. But I believe Deltek makes other software for software development.

https://superuser.com/questions/580843/is-there-any-way-for-an-individual-to-learn-deltek-vision?noredirect=1#comment710957_580843

If this would be acceptable here on PM I will re-ask it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Ryan, Welcome to PMSE! Unfortunately, this question is not a good fit for the site. I applaud your initiative in trying to get experience on this tool.  Perhaps you can try looking for people that have experience with the application and pay them to teach you. Or offer to intern at a firm that uses it in exchange for exposure to the software and training materials.  Best of luck!